# Is there a way to perform a validation on the number of digits in a number? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate a CAB code of a bank.

The rules are that the CAB it MUST be numeric, and composed by 5 digits.
I'm trying to validate this into a **FormRequest** class in Laravel 5.3

I've tried to set the validation like this:

```
"cab" => "required|max:5|min:5",
```

It works, but if the user pass a normal character (non numeric) in between, the validation passes since the string does not exceed the 5 chars length. So this is bad.

I've tried to set the validation like this:

```
"cab" => "required|max:5|min:5|numeric",
```

but if the user pass **55555** it will fail because the number is greater than **5**.

I'm wondering if there's a way to perform a validation that says:

*The input must be numeric, but the count of the total digits can't be greater than 5.*

Am I missing something? 
Thanks for any help

Comment: `digits:5` [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-digits)

Comment: what a shame. I apologize, completely missed out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `digits:value` or `digits_between:min,max`

Comment: Thanks! Also @Mark Baker gave me the answer in the comment above.